# Check if domain have record CNAME and point to my server

Tags: php, dns, record, cloudflare

I need to check if my users have add correctly the CNAME record but with this code I get empty array

```
<?php

$domain="martinashop.club";
if(checkdnsrr($domain,"CNAME")) {
  echo "Passed";
} else {
  echo "Failed";
}
echo "<br>";

print_r(dns_get_record($domain,DNS_CNAME));
echo "<br>";
print_r(dns_check_record($domain,"CNAME"));
?>
```

I not understan why not get the RECORD
my domain using Clouflare maybe this get a error?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing any CNAME records for that domain, hence the empty array. If you use DNS_ANY, you'll get the A records for it.

Comment: Hi  I have CNAME for subdomain start.martinashop.club and A for main domain (@) to my server IP but I need to know if start.martinashop.club point to my destination I thinked that I can recovery from main domain I have try too with $domain="start.martinashop.club"; ma array is always empty

Comment: I get the proper response when using start.martinashop.club, an array with a single response. If you're not getting that, then either your local DNS hasn't updated, or it's being blocked.

Comment: with subdomain work, but only if no proxied from cloudflare

Comment: Proxied domains mean it will be routed to Cloudflare, then Cloudflare passes along the traffic. It won't pass along the original CNAME in your DNS.

Comment: there is no way to get the cname from cloudflare?

Comment: Not if they're proxied, no, because the traffic will run through Cloudflare first. The CNAME becomes invisible to the outside world. This goes for any proxied DNS record in Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a CNAME on a naked domain.

CNAMEs can only exist as single records and not combined with any other resource records. Since a domain always has a SOA and NS record, you cannot use a CNAME for the domain. This is specified in [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), section 3.6.2.

Comment: Hi @justin I have 
CNAME for subdomain start.martinashop.club
and
A for main domain (@) to my server IP
but I need to know if start.martinashop.club point to my destination

I thinked that I can recovery from main domain
I have try too with $domain="start.martinashop.club";
ma array is always empty

Comment: with subdomain work, but only if no proxied from cloudflare